# bash shell string compare

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to store 'M' status files in bash variable.

For checking the status, I trimmed and split each line of 'svn status'.

But if statement does not work correctly.

I mean, I have several 'M' status files.
But no files echo "Modified" in below script.

Could you comments what's wrong this script?

```
svn_copy2()
{
   IFS=''
   svn_files=()
   while read line
   do
      svn_files+=(${line})
   done < <(svn st)
   dump_files=$()

   for f in ${svn_files[@]};
   do
      sign=$(echo ${f} | xargs | cut -d " " -f 1)
      echo ${sign} > result
      if [[ $sign == "M" ]]; then
         echo "Modified"
      fi
   done
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm seeing some questionable code here. Try running it through [ShellCheck](//shellcheck.net) and fixing any problems it points out.

Comment: If you want to track down a specific problem, use `bash -x yourscript` to run with tracing enabled; there are too many bugs here (most of them related to missing quoting) for us to guess which one is your immediate problem.

Comment: In general, though: let's say you have a line `M path.txt`. When you run `svn_files+=(${line})`, that adds `M` as one entry and `path.txt` as a second one, because you didn't quote it as `svn_files+=( "$line" )`. You have the same problem when you use `for f in ${svn_files[@]}` instead of `for f in "${svn_files[@]}"`, and _yet again_ when you use `echo $f` instead of `echo "$f"`.

Comment: BTW, think about `declare -A svn_files=( ); while read -r mod_char filename; do svn_files[$filename]=$mod_char; done < <(svn st)` -- then you can iterate over `for file in "${!svn_files[@]}"` to get the names, and look up `${svn_files[$file]}` to get the mod_char value back for any given name. It won't work right for names with leading or trailing spaces, but it's a messy situation if you _have_ any of those in the first place.

Comment: What is the point in using `xargs`? `f` holds a single word, and a plain `xargs` without parameters just does an `echo`. Hence you are doing an `echo` of a single word. Then you pipe the single word into `cut` and take the first field, which is of course that single word again. You could have written equally well `sign=$f`.